# VS2010 C#: Delay when opening a file inside IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have this annoying problem. Each time I *double click* on (*open*) a file in the *Solution Explorer*, it takes around 5 seconds to open.

It doesn't matter if its a small file or a large file.

Does anyone know how I can avoid this delay?

Comment: Look at the status pane in the bottom-right corner. What does it say when you open a file?

Answer (score 3):

You might have a visual studio plugin that is over processing your files (resharper, coderush, visual assist)?

Comment: +1 mentioning the plugins, had the problem with resharper

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to work out why there is the delay in the first place.

Try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what is happening.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I have been messing around with *Process Monitor* and each time the delay happens, it looks like *Visual Studio 2010* runs through each of the files in my project, using 3 operations on each file (`CreateFile`, `QueryBasicInformationFile` and `CloseFile`). More stuff is happening, but the 3 operations seems like the major part of whats happening. Does this ring a bell?

Comment: @Chau: VS does check for open files being updated outside VS (this can be configured), that'll be the checks on other files.

Comment: Well this delay does not happen all the time - just in short periods and then changing files are done fast. I really don't know what to look for :S

Answer (score 0):

It could be Intellisense working away.  My laptop is an older AMD Turion RM 2.2 and along with the 5400rpm drive, VS 2010 can be a lumbering beast loading up projects.